# java - reading input lines and outputting duplicates

Tags: java, text, line

So I'm learning about reading textfiles and such, and I'm trying to make a program that reads the input one line at a time and outputs the current line if and only if it is smaller than any other line read so far. Smaller is with respect to the usual order on Strings, as defined by String.compareTo().

When I try to run my code, I get errors "List cannot be resolved to a type" and "ArrayList can not be resolved to a type". I'm confused as to why I got this error in my program, and was wondering if there is something else I'm supposed to use?

```
package comp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Part2 {

    public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
        List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        String line;
        String shortest = allStrings.get(0);
        while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            for(String s: allStrings) {
                if(s.length()>shortest.length()) {
                    shortest = s;
                    line = shortest;
                }
            }
            allStrings.add(line);

            for (String text: allStrings) {
                w.println(text);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader r;
            PrintWriter w;
            if (args.length == 0) {
                r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            } else if (args.length == 1) {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
                w = new PrintWriter(System.out);                
            } else {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
                w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
            }
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            doIt(r, w);
            w.flush();
            long stop = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Execution time: " + 10e-9 * (stop-start));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole class? I see bugs within doIt, but I would like to debug the code before proving an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use integer for min length:

```
public class Part2 {

    public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
        List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        int minLength = 0;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            if (minLength == 0 || minLength > line.length()) {
                allStrings.add(line);
                minLength = line.length();
            }
        }

        for (String text : allStrings) {
            w.println(text);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader r;
            PrintWriter w;
            if (args.length == 0) {
                r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            } else if (args.length == 1) {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
                w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            } else {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
                w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
            }
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            doIt(r, w);
            w.flush();
            long stop = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Execution time: " + 10e-9 * (stop - start));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Input file**:

```
1111111
222222222
3333333333
444
```

**Output**:

```
1111111
444
```

Also your code has following bug:

```
    List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<>();

 // It throws IndexOutOfBoundsException!!!
    String shortest = allStrings.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of problems here. If you ran your code, you would have gotten an `IndexOutOfBoundException` in `doIt()` because your `allStrings` list is empty and hence when you call `String shortest = allStrings.get(0);` your calling something that is not in your list.

Also, the logic `if(s.length()>shortest.length()))` is a bit odd as essentially you really only comparing the Strings in your List and not against what you have read from the file. Hence you'll never determine if the line you've read from the file is *smaller* than any of the lines you already have.

Finally, this code ... `for (String text: allStrings) {w.println(text); }` ... to write your file is in the loop, hence your writing the String each loop iteration.

You don't need the *shortest* variable, just use a boolean to indicate if the string you've read in is shorter than those already in your list and only if it is, add it to your list.

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    List<String> shortestStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = r.readLine();
    shortestStrings.add(line);

    while(line != null) {
        boolean isShortert = Boolean.TRUE;
        for(String s: shortestStrings) {
            if(line.length() > s.length()) {
                isShortert = Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        }
        if(isShortert) {
            shortestStrings.add(line);
        }
        line = r.readLine();
    }

    for (String text: shortestStrings) {
        w.println(text);
    }
}
```